# Firebase security rules not working - Can't figure out why

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

is there some one that knows how security rules for firestore works?

I'm trying to do something like this but it doesn't work (I don't get access to data).

```
match /contents/{contentID} {
      allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/reserved/permissions).data.contents.hasAny([contentID])
      allow create, update, delete : if false
    }
```

It seems the problem is contentID since if I do this

```
match /contents/{contentID} {
      allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/reserved/permissions).data.contents.hasAny(["3"])
      allow create, update, delete : if false
    }
```

and update the document located in user/reserved/permission adding "3" to contents (that is an array field of the document ) it works. It's like contentID is not converted right.

Can someone explains why?

**UPDATE**

The client code is just

```
 firestore()
      .collection('contents')
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
         console.log(querySnapsho)
       })
```

and it return always null. If I change the rule in

```
 match /contents/{contentID} {
          allow read: true
          allow create, update, delete : if false
        }
```

it works. So the problem is with the rule

Comment: Please edit the question to show the relevant app code that triggers these rules, as well as the document data you're working with.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone can reproduce the issue.

Comment: There is no code triggering it I guess, this is just a security rule.

Comment: If there is no client code, then the rule has no effect on anything. The whole point of security rules is to limit what client apps can do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query).  I strongly suggest reading that documentation to understand how the system work.

Your query attempts to get all documents in the collection.  The rules deny that query because it's not certain if the client actually has read access to each any every document.  It will **not** evaluate a `get()` for each possible document - that simply doesn't scale (and it would be very expensive for you for large collections).

Your client app should be able to `get()` any individual document where the rule evaluates to true, but you won't be able to perform queries against the collection like this.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is well written. The problem is that the generic query get() on the entire collection "contents" it's not allowed after this kind of rules are activated (and it makes sense since this behaviour is designed to reduce the resources needed for a query)

Read this to understand the logic

https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-does-it-mean-that-firestore-security-rules-are-not-filters-68ec14f3d003